# Symfony 2 relations issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I nead help.

I have 3 entities. Book, Category And BookCategory - book can have multiple categories so i used another table.

I can easily acces Book and Category useing BookCategory table but i dont know how to do this by Book->BookCategory->Category.

```
    class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text")
     */
    private $name;

     /**
      * @var Category
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="Category")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    private $parent;

class BookCategory
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
      * @var Book
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="BookCategory")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    private $bookId;

     /**
      * @var Category
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="BookCategory")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    private $categoryId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="priority", type="integer")
     */
    private $priority;

class Book
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="text")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="text")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     */
    private $price;
```

How i need to config my entities or how to make my DQL to achive wanted results?

Comment: In Addition to what @TimoSta said: You need to set the `inversedBy` attributes of the annotations correctly. Currently you should be getting errors because they should be set to a property of the entity in `targetEntity` not an entity itself.

Comment: @RoToRa can you show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, you only established the relationship from `BookCategory` to `Book`. As you said, that enables you to get the `Book` associated to one `BookCategory`.
To go the other way and get all `BookCategory` that belong to one book, you also need to specify this relationship. What you want is a `OneToMany` relationship from `Book` to `BookCategory`.

```
<?php

//...
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany;

class Book
{
    //...

    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="BookCategory", mappedBy="bookId")
    */
    private $bookCategories;

    //...
}

class BookCategory
{

     //...

     /**
      * @var Book
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="bookCategories")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    private $bookId;

     //...

}
```

After adding the necessary getters and setters, `getBookCategories()` will give you an Array with all `BookCategory` that belong to the `Book`.

For more details, have a look at the official Symfony2 documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata

**Edit:**
Included `use` statement. Corrected `inversedBy` property for `bookId`.

Comment: Now im getting Annotation @onetomany was never imported when i try to generate entities.

Comment: That's probably because you did not import the Annotation via `use`. Have a look at my edit.
Also make sure you take into account what @RoToRa commented to your question. The `inversedBy` property of the `ManyToOne` relationship of the property `bookId` of your `Book` class has to be adapted. I also corrected it in my edit.